# Oracle coherence cache not working - gives NPE

Tags: java, caching, distributed-caching, oracle-coherence

I am trying to build a simple caching application using coherence. I am able to bring up the service and push or pop value from the cache via command line (cmd). But when I try to do the same using Java code, I am getting the following error:
null

> Exception in thread "main"
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.learn.coherence.main.TestCacheMainOne.main(TestCacheMainOne.java:14)

The code is fairly simple and small.
Line with the exception is

> NamedCache cache = CacheFactory.getCache("VirtualCache");

```
import com.tangosol.net.CacheFactory; 
import com.tangosol.net.NamedCache; 

public class TestCacheMainOne { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    NamedCache cache = CacheFactory.getCache("VirtualCache");
    System.out.println(cache); 
    String key = "key1"; 
    String value = "value1"; 
    cache.put(key, value); 
    String receivedValue = (String) cache.get(key); 
    System.out.println(receivedValue); 
  } 
}
```

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: That can't be line 14.

Comment: Sorry I messed up the lines numbers there while trying to eliminate the useless stuff. The line throwing the exception is
cache.put(key,value)

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build a client application,
probably you missing configuration file in the class path.

take a look in this guide.

[Oracle Coherence Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15357_01/coh.360/e15726/gs_example.htm#COHCG5032)
Step 2: Configure the Client Side

Comment: Hi Arkadiy,
Sorry I wasn't able to understand that since I am so new to the caching scene.
All I am trying to do here is start an application A that can load some elements into the cache with can be accessed by another application B running on the same machine by using the cache name or something similar. I am not looking to use a different server for the cache. I just need to be able to make changes to the cache so that both application A and B can make changes and it reflects at both places.

Again I realize this might not make a lot of sense but if you can, could you please explain it ?

Comment: Hi, the code should work. Please share the console window or any logs that you have.

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException at cache.put(key, value) means CacheFactory coundn't find "VirtualCache" cache.
Check coherence-cache-config.xml, make sure the config contains something like:

```
<caching-scheme-mapping>
    <cache-mapping>
        <cache-name>VirtualCache</cache-name>
        <scheme-name>YourScheme</scheme-name>
    </cache-mapping>
</caching-scheme-mapping>
<caching-schemes>
    <remote-cache-scheme>
        <scheme-name>YourScheme</scheme-name>
        <service-name>ExtendTcpCacheService</service-name>
        <initiator-config>
            <tcp-initiator>
                <remote-addresses>
                    <socket-address>
                        <address>your_coherence_server</address>
                        <port>xxxx</port>
                    </socket-address>
                </remote-addresses>
                ...
            </tcp-initiator>
            ...
        </initiator-config>
        ...
    </remote-cache-scheme>
    ...
</caching-schemes>
```

You should also check coherence-factory-config.xml, it has the path of coherence log file, which contains server connection status.

Comment: The following cache mapping is defined in the default cache configuration file. With this we should be able to create any cache: 
    <cache-mapping>
      <cache-name>*</cache-name>
      <scheme-name>example-distributed</scheme-name>
    </cache-mapping>